# Sync Schema Versioning

Tags: cocoa, core-data, syncservices

Now that I have registered my sync services schema, how do I update it to my new model version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out from the docs..
¨ is highly recommended that you register the schema periodically even if it does not change—for example, register the schema each time your application launches. However, if a schema changes, update it with caution because changing a schema may cause records to be deleted and cause some clients to slow sync.¨

We need just to re-register the schema..